Limiting SSH/HTTP/etc. access to LAN only on IOS-XE
On a Cisco ISR 1000 series router, I have SSH, and the HTTP(s) management interface running. The router is doing PAT.
Issue is, all of these services are accessible from WAN too. For a temporary workaround, I added an ACL on the WAN interface to block 22/80/443 ports, but that rules out the possibility of doing port-forwarding with those external ports.
Permitting the LAN IP range only isn't a good solution either, as there are VPN gateways on LAN, and remote VPN users should be able to reach SSH/HTTP.
Essentially, I'm looking for the equivalent of telling the SSH and HTTP servers to only listen on the LAN interface.
Current config:
version 17.9
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
! Call-home is enabled by Smart-Licensing.
service call-home
service unsupported-transceiver
platform qfp utilization monitor load 80
platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
platform hardware throughput crypto 50000
!
hostname x
!
boot-start-marker
boot system flash bootflash:c1100-universalk9.17.09.05a.SPA.bin
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip domain name local
!
!
!
login on-success log
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
subscriber templating
vtp version 1
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
memory free low-watermark processor 65995
!
diagnostic bootup level minimal
!
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
enable secret 9 x
!
username x privilege 15 secret 9 x
!
redundancy
 mode none
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
policy-map control-plane-in
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip access-group WAN-ACL in
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/1
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/2
 switchport mode access
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/3
 switchport mode access
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.0.0
 ip nat inside
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.0.1
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip forward-protocol nd
ip nat inside source list 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
ip ssh version 2
!
!
ip access-list extended WAN-ACL
 10 deny tcp any any eq 22
 20 deny tcp any any eq telnet
 30 deny udp any any eq tftp
 40 deny tcp any any eq www
 50 deny tcp any any eq 443
 60 permit ip any any
!
ip access-list standard 1
 10 permit 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 20 0
 logging synchronous
 transport input none
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 20 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 transport input ssh
line vty 5 14
 exec-timeout 20 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 transport input ssh



Please edit your question to include the router configuration. We cannot guess where you may have gone wrong.

There's nothing "gone wrong", I just don't know how to configure the router according to my requirements. Included the current config.

You went wrong somewhere in your attempt to configure it. We cannot just make up configurations for you without seeing how it is configured now.

Also, that is not the full configuration. Where are the VTY lines where you would put the access-class to limit router management?

Added the full config. I don't have access-class in VTY anywhere, since the reason for my question's existence is not knowing how to do what I'm asking.

And we could have seen that and given you some guidance if you had included it right away.

By the way, you do not use the ip default-gateway command on a router that has routing enabled; that is for devices like layer-2 switches. Instead, you use the ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 command. See this answer (among other here) about that.

When you use the lines like the VTY lines to manage your router, you apply your access list to them using access-class instead of access-group like you do on an interface.
You can do something like:
line vty 0 15
 exec-timeout 20 0
 logging synchronous
 login local
 transport input ssh
 access-class 1 in

You should really disable the HTTP server altogether. That is a basic security thing to do.
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server


Is there any way to give it an extended ACL instead? I need to allow up to 3 subnets to access SSH, as remote VPN clients have source IPs that are in different subnets.

You can add multiple permit statements in a standard ACL. There really is not a reason to use an extended because the destination is already known and the same for all your permits.

I agree with the recommendation to disable the HTTP server/secure-server unless you REALLY need the web interface. If you do, you can run them on alternate ports (10443 or something) to free up 443.
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr1000/software/configuration/xe-17/asr1000-sw-config-xe-17/webui-asr.html
There is a large guide for general recommendations for improving security for the router:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-xe-16/220270-use-cisco-ios-xe-hardening-guide.html
Look at the part on secure interactive management sessions.
